# Setting FROM Email Address in FREE SmarterMail 15 for Delivery Failure Notices

Tags: iis-7, email-bounces

I have Free SmarterMail 15 setup on a Windows Server to allow CDONTS and php mail to send emails from contact forms.

When the `to` email address is invalid, a delivery failure notice is sent to the `from` email address. However SmarterMail doesn't send the message from an email address, its blank and causing some mail systems to mark the errors as SPAM.

I was hoping someone knew where the setting exists to change the email address. I have looked everywhere and even made a few tests and still nothing.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

They have not provided any setting to change the email address than "System Administrator" to send a mail Delivery notification.

However, you can create an event to send a mail from a specific email address to the < from > mail account (recipient of the mail delivery failure) with a notification. Please check if it works for you.

In order to create such events, please follow the steps:

1) Go to the Domains >> Manage Domain

2) Go to the Settings >> Domains Settings >> Events

3) Create a new Event

--> Event Name : Delivery notification

--> Event Category: EMail

--> Event Type: Message Received

--> Subject [Checked] : Equal : Delivery Failure

--> Enable [Checked]

4) Go to the Action Tab

--> Add Action

--> Action : Send Email

--> From Email address: < Enter Your valid Email address i.e. systemadmin@domain.com >

--> To address: #toaddress#

--> Subject: Delivery failure notification received

--> Body: TYPE ANY NOTIFICATION MAIL FOR THE DELIVERY FAILURE NOTIFICATION

That's it!

I have checked it on my server and it works for me:)

Comment: thank you. I looked through the global event types and domain level event types and didn't see any event type about mail delivery failure. Which one would I need to select?

Comment: @imvain2 , I have just edited my answer. Please have a check it.

Comment: thank you for your update, Its not working. I matched the settings (or used my own in case of email addresses). I even went as far as just using the from/to email address as actual email addresses and not a variable.